# How EF will get the system generated ID of a newly added object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application + i am using EF6.0. and sometimes i can not understand how EF handles things internally. for example i have two entities named; Technology & Rack. where the `Technology.TechnologyID` is a system generated ID , while the `Rack.RackID` is user defined key and will be = to the `Technology.TechnologyID.` .so i have the following method to add a new technology , then to add a new rack and assign the `Rack.RackID` to be equal to the system generated `Technology.TechnologyID`.

```
    Technology technology = new Technology
                    {
                        IsCompleted = false,
                        IsDeleted = true,
                        TypeID = technologyypeID,
                        Tag = "CAB" + max.ToString(),
                        PartialTag = max,
                        StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                        IT360ID = dbresource.RESOURCEID,//,,
                        IsManaged = rj.Technology == null ? true : rj.Technology.IsManaged


                    };



                    rj.Rack.RackID = technology.TechnologyID;
SAVE():
```

now at the beginning i though that i above will not work , since when i try:-

```
rj.Rack.RackID = technology.TechnologyID;
```

the TechnologyID will not be available at this time, and using VS i found that at run time the TechnologyID will be equal to zero :-

[image]

so i am not sure how EF handle this ? and it force the `Rack.RackID` to be equal to the `Technology.TechnologyID` , although at run-time the technology-id will be zero. here is the sql statement that have been generated from the sql profiler :-

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Racks]([RackID], [DataCenterID], [ZoneID], [IT360SiteID])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3)
select [timestamp]
from [dbo].[Racks]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [RackID] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 bigint',@0=128,@1=3,@2=2,@3=4
```

not sure how the `128` was assigned altohugh at run time the value was zero?

Comment: Most likely EF knows about the relationships so if you have linked the objects through normal object reference properties, EF knows where to retrieve the ID after inserting the parent object into the database.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you adivce more on this ? although this is a great feature of EF , but it is totally confusing how this magic happened ?

Comment: No, I can't, I don't have enough experience with EF, it's only a thought, someone else will have to either verify it or say I'm wrong (it has been known to happen on occasion :))

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new `Technology` object and its `TechnologyID` is database generated. When it is inserted, EF follows the insert with a select to retrieve the generated value. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @TechnologyID int
SELECT @TechnologyID = [TechnologyID]
FROM [dbo].[Technology]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [TechnologyID] = scope_identity()
```

The results are then used by Entity Framework to fix up the `Technology` entity, so that when you then insert the `Rack` object, its `RackID` (which is not database generated) is correctly set to the new `TechnologyID` (as you specified in your code). The `@0` parameter used when the select is issued on the `Racks` table to retrieve the timestamp is also set to the new value (128 in your example).

Answer (score 0):

When you're making your assignment `rj.Rack.RackID = technology.TechnologyID;` your new `technology` object has not yet been committed to the database, and thus won't have an assigned `TechnologyID` property. Without changing your mappings/schema, the simplest way to address your problem would be to save once to commit `technology` and assign it a `TechnologyID`, assign that as your `RackID`, and then save again.

The longer, more proper solution, would be to have `RackID` be an actual identity property, and instead use a foreign-key relationship from `Rack` to `Technology` with the appropriate EF mappings.

Comment: but as i said i am not facing any problem in my current code,,, i am trying to understand how EF handle this magic,, did u read my question well,, you are saying i need to save my technology object first to get its id.... but i am not saving it ,, and EF magically assign the technologyid to the RACK ... so my question is how did this magic happened !!!!

Comment: and sorry for the down vote as ur answer is not related to my question .... & seems you are confused as i do